# manifest.json:2 Manifest: Line: 2, column: 2, Unexpected token

Tags: sharepoint-2013, manifest.json

Good day.

I have tried to add a manifest file to my SharePoint site with no success.

Please keep in mind that this is my first attempt at adding a manifest file.

So i created a manifest.jason file containing the following code:

```
{
    "name": "",
    "short_name": "",
    "icons": [
        {
      "src": "SiteAssets/smallBlock.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "SiteAssets/bigBlock.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "theme_color": "#790B0B"
  "background_color": "#790B0B",
  "display": "standalone",
}
```

I have also included in my masterpage like so :

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/Style%20Library/scripts/manifest.json">
```

...This does not work

The error i get when working with the chrome dev tools is the following:

> manifest.json:2  Manifest: Line: 2, column: 2, Unexpected token.

Please can someone assist.

Answer (score 0):

In my previous removed reply I said I had a feeling that Sharepoint doesn't like requesting JSON files from site folders, I was right. Look at the response of the manifest call, it gives you a strange js/html file. Instead of using manifest.json, use manifest.webmanifest, like so:

```
href="/Style%20Library/scripts/manifest.webmanifest"
```

This completely resolved it for me, I hope it does for you as well.